# Add a choice list(dropdown) from 2 different entities in a single table in Symfony 2

Tags: forms, symfony

I am looking for a method on how to possibly create a single dropdown for my form in symfony 2 that contains the value of the field 'abbr1' and 'abbr2' from a single record in table Params.

Lets say i have a single record in my table Params.

id: 1

title: sample

abbr1: qw12

abbr2: er34

Now i want to pick abbr1 and abbr2 as the value of a single dropdown. I have created a form but i dont know how to make both of them a choice. I can only pick them as a property one at a time. Here is my code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add(
            'desiredAbbr', 
            'entity', 
            array(
                'class' => 'FooBarBundle:Params',
                'property' => 'abbr1',
                //'property' => 'abbr2',
                )
            )
        ->add('save','submit',array('label'=>'Submit'))
    ;
}
```

Any Suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Update:
The expected dropdown value would look like this in html format:

```
{% for par in parameters %}
    <select>
        <option>{{param.abbr1}}</option>  {# qw12 #}
        <option>{{param.abbr2}}</option>  {# er34 #}
    </select>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: A HTML select input has only one value attribute. That's why you can only provide one property ... Bu you can concatenate your two properties in a new one and use this new one in your form.

Comment: @Alsatian  i think i dont need concatenation in my case. Thanks for the feedback. I also updated my code above for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I missed that you want them as value, not as label. Then you should change you form like this

```
$choices = $options['abbrChoices'];

$builder->add('desiredAbbr', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => $choices,
));

// in configureOptions method
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'abbrChoices' => array(),
));
```

In controller where you create the form

```
$params = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Params')->findAll();
$choices = array();
foreach ($params as $p) {
    // key will be used as option value, value as option title
    $choices[$p->getAbbr1()] = $p->getAbbr1();
    $choices[$p->getAbbr2()] = $p->getAbbr2();
}

$form = $this->createForm(myform::class, array(), array('abbrChoices' => $choices));
```

BUT. How are you going to use this choice?

Comment: he doesn't want it as label but as value.

Comment: @DenisAlimov thanks for the feedback. I also updated my code for clarification. Please review it again thanks

Comment: @Uc.IT_samuel ok, I've edited part related to generating choices list. try it

Comment: @DenisAlimov should i just add the _'abbrChoices' => array(),_ in my existing $resolver?

Should it look like this? 

$resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Foo\BarBundle\Entity\PickMe', 'abbrChoices' => array()
        ));

Comment: @Uc.IT_samuel yes, exactly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115384/discussion-between-uc-it-samuel-and-denis-alimov).